# SignalR - Change server timeout response

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, signalr

I've created a SignalR application but when I set the KeepAliveInternal and ClientTimeOutInterval a value in the hub configuration, the application ignores it and always sets it to "30,000ms" for both.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddRazorPages();
   services.AddSignalR().AddHubOptions<ActivityHub>(options => {
      options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
      options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
   });
}
```

I've read the SignalR Net Core docs and there is no limit for these two properties. The timeout always is "30,000" even though I set those to different values.

Comment: Are you using automatic reconnect on the client-side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> when i set the KeepAliveInternal and ClientTimeOutInterval a value in the hub configuration, the application ignore it and always set to "30,000ms" for both.

For SignalR JavaScript client, the default [`serverTimeoutInMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40microsoft/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#servertimeoutinmilliseconds) value is 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds). If you set `KeepAliveInterval` of HubOptions with a value > 30 seconds, but not specify an appropriate value for `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` of HubConnection on client side, the connection will be terminated with an error, like below.

[image]

To fix it, you can try to set `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` of your HubConnection, like below.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
    .build();

connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 120000;
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Note:

In my above test, I configure SignalR hubs with below code snippet, and we can find a ping message is sent automatically per 60s.

```
hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

Comment: Where are you creating that new HubConnectionBuilder object?

Comment: @orangecaterpillar It can be created when you need it, but that already depends a lot on what you do

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to the official documentation for [configuring server options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options)

You may try to configure it as following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    });
}
```

Or for a single hub:

```
services.AddSignalR().AddHubOptions<MyHub>(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem back then, and what I changed was simple. I changed `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` since in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet) you can see that those intervals are in seconds.

[image: server config]

So my configuration code now is like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds SignalR.
/// </summary>
private void AddSignalR(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.ClientTimeoutInterval);
        hubOptions.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.HandshakeTimeout);
        hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.KeepAliveInterval);
        hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.EnableDetailedErrors;
        hubOptions.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.MaximumReceiveMessageSize;
        hubOptions.StreamBufferCapacity = this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.StreamBufferCapacity;
    }).AddAzureSignalR(azureOptions =>
    {
        azureOptions.ConnectionCount = this.azureConfiguration.SignalR.ServerConnectionCount;
    });
}
```

Comment: The returned object is always a TimeSpan, FromMintues and FromSeconds define the argument being passed into the factory method, and not what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer concerning **SignalR in Blazor-Apps**.

As of now serverTimeoutInMilliseconds cannot be set in Startup.cs together with the other HubOptions.  But you can solve the problem as follows:

**.NET 6**

In _Layout.cshtml after `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>`
add

```
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            let c = builder.build();
            c.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 60000;
            c.keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds = 30000;
            builder.build = () => {
                return c;
            };
        };
    });
</script>
```

([Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18840))

This will set serverTimeoutInMilliseconds to 60 seconds and the keepAliveInterval to 30 seconds.

**.NET 8**

In _Layout.cshtml after `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>`
add

```
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            builder.withServerTimeout(60000).withKeepAliveInterval(30000);
        };
    });
</script>
```

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-signalr-timeouts-and-keep-alive-on-the-client))

This will set serverTimeoutInMilliseconds to 60 seconds and the keepAliveInterval to 30 seconds.